# when I change the url, react-router onEnter function didn't work

Tags: react-router

```js
var routeMap = {
    "/login": Login,
    "/place": Place,
    "/article": Arcticle
};
function initBar(url){
    if(document.getElementById('bar')){
        ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(document.getElementById('bar'));
    }
    var Bar;
    if(url=="/login"){
        Bar = null;
    }else{
        Bar = <NavBar items={itemArray} />;
    }

    if(Bar){
        ReactDOM.render(
            <div>
                {Bar}
            </div>,
            document.getElementById('bar')
        )
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(
        // <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
        <div id="container">
           <Router path='/' component={routeMap[url]} >
            {
                Object.keys(routeMap).map(function (item) {
                    return (
                        <Router path={item} component={routeMap[item]} onEnter={item}/>
                    )
                })
            }
        </Router>
        </div>,
        document.getElementById('content')
    );
```

the onEnter event only work when the component init, when I change the url from /login to /place, the onEnter event didn't work. If anywhere is wrong?I am learning react by myself.

Comment: you've passed a `string` to onEnter hook, but it should be a `function`

Comment: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#onenternextstate-replace-callback

Comment: sorry, In my code i was  write the "onEnter={initBar(item)} ", here i write wrong. but it also didn't work when I change the url. only work when component init.

Comment: try `onEnter={ initBar.bind(this, item) }`

Comment: currently `initBar` invokes  immediately. Since  the `initBar` function doesnt return a function , so `onEnter` hook won't get a function to invoke.

Comment: It works. Thank you very much!